# How to apply shipping charge for particular product

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have used flat_rate shipping method which charges 20 Rs for cart total in magento shop.

I have created a shopping cart price rule, according to it if cart total is greater than and equal to 200 Rs then no shipping charge will be apply on cart total. It works correctly.

I have a product which has price approximate 2000 Rs (it means greater than 200), according to above rule no shipping charge will apply on cart total, but I want to apply shipping charge 10 Rs on this product.

How to do that?

Comment: Did you get your point?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new attribute to your products from 
Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes called "Free shipping" set the type to "Dropdown" with Yes/No options.

Assign that new attribute you have created to the Attribute Groups you want.

More info  here: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html#gref

That process will add a new attribute to your products
[image]

And then on your Shipping Cart Price Rule you can use something like this (customise it to the discount details you want).

[image]

Now you can set Free Shipping only to the products you want on the backend.

Comment: Hello @St0iK, I don't want to change my previous functionality, but want to add new rule for particular product.